# Wiibalance board java example

Tags: java, wii-balanceboard

Does anyone have some source for connecting to a Wiibalance board using java?  I have looked at Wiiboard_simple project on google, but it never seems to connect correctly.  I have seen other examples in C# and javascript, but none in java.

Answer (score 0):

Check out some of the libraries on the WiiBrew.org site:

- [Wiimote Libraries for Java](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote/Library#WiiRemoteJ.2C_a_Java_library_for_the_Wii_Remote)

I have only been looking at this from an Android perspective, so its not entirely useful for PC-based Java.

---

However, for Android info, including some Android Java links, check my answer on this thread:

- [How to connect wii balance board with android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14781177/383414)

Basically it links to:

- @Ben Mordue's answer on: [Is it possible for an android device to read information from the wii controller and nunchuck?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9669315/383414)
- [Blues-IME project for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-bluez-ime/) - you might be able to use some of that code
- WiiBrew.org pages for [Wiimote](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote) & [Wii Balance Board](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wii_Balance_Board)

---

### Update:

Last night I was able to get the Balance Board correctly communicating to the Android device based on the library, and the info on the wiibrew.org site. It really is not that difficult once you get your head around working with HEX commands.

The important part is to realise that the Balance Board is treated in much the same way as a Nunchuck or Classic Controller. Since most of the libraries can access these Extensions, it should be easy to adapt them to also detect the Balance Board extension.