# How to connect wii balance board with android

Tags: android, wiimote, wii, wii-balanceboard

How to connect Wii balance board with android?

Is there are any useful Library in android and how to use it?

My goal now is to connect it together and can receive data from it.

I'm new with android and Bluetooth development

Comment: The Wii Balance Board is mostly no different than a regular Wii Remote.  It can be paired with your phone in the same way.  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=672884

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this answer useful: [Is it possible for an android device to read information from the wii controller and nunchuck?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9669315/383414) (quoted below with thanks to @Ben Mordue)

> Have a look at this open source project:
>   http://code.google.com/p/android-bluez-ime/

---

### Update:

I first installed the APK file on Galaxy Nexus and it works. I have checked the code out of the repo, and it builds fine, and it relatively easy to understand.

It comes in 3 projects - to use Wiimote, you need to install all 3 projects. The one is just used as a flag to allow the service to try for a Wiimote (considering not all ROMs support that level of HID interaction).

---

I also found these resources on WiiBrew.org:

- http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote
- http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wii_Balance_Board

I used the Wiimote link to understand the Bluez-IME code.

---

### Update 2:

Last night I got the board to communicate with my Android phone correctly. I did this by starting with the Bluez-IME code linked above, and modifying it based on the wiibrew.org info.

The trick is that the Balance Board is like a wiimote with an Extension. So its like a Nunchuk or Classic Controller, but just with a different device ID to look for.

For my initial demo, I just searched for all code that uses a Nunchuk, and duplicated it for a Balance Board. Then to initialise the MODE to use channel 0x32, as per the wiibrew Balance Board page.

---

### Update 3:

I just stumbled across this app on the store: [FitScales](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.paulburton.fitscales)

And the developer has shared his code on github: [paulburton / fitscales](https://github.com/paulburton/fitscales)

Comment: How did you get to the calibration data?

Comment: @ethrbunny I didn't get as far as calibrating it. As I was trying to figure out what the data represented, I found a great app that was already written that did what I needed ([WiiScale](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.broschb.wiiscale)). So that pet project got left alone...