# How to read and translate data from wii balance board

Tags: java, android, wiimote, wii, wii-balanceboard

By the advise from [How to connect wii balance board with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660159/how-to-connect-wii-balance-board-with-android)

Through 0x32,

- According to data pattern below , Byte no. 0 and 1 is serve for core buttons. Another 8 bytes left is for the extension (Balance Board)
- From my observation, Bit no. 2,4,6,8 are change for a little bit swing (Ex. bit no. 2's normal value without any pressure is 49, and when I stand on the board, it changed to 50,51,52,... But the other (Bit no. 3,5,7,9 is too much swing. (Ex. from -127 to 127 (for every bit))
- I have try with 2 balance board, the data value when no any pressure is different

This picture below show about data(in hex) transmit captured from Logcat

http://image.ohozaa.com/i/fcd/gpWyHN.png

**** As you see, value from bit no. 2,4,6,8 not changed, but 3,5,7,9 is changing a little evenif there no pressure on it.

**** At line number 11, through port 0x21, Is it calibration data ?

So, the next question is, 
- What is the meaning of each bit of these data.
- How to translate it to weight and location of Center of Gravity ?

Please help!
I have no any clue about this from tried for 1 weeks, and deadline is coming T_T

** addition picture about data in decimal value when standing and not stand on it in the comment below

Comment: Addition.

- Data in decimal format
http://image.ohozaa.com/view2/wJKQ4dJL7C3h15BS

- Data in decimal format when I stand on the board
http://image.ohozaa.com/view2/wJKQ4zIrp35usWWg

- Data without any pressure in another balance board
http://image.ohozaa.com/view2/wJKQ2NP1Z6ug6jiS